# Asp.Net DataList bind array of ImageUrls

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, bind, datalist

I am trying to make a grid of thumbnails using a datalist. I have an array of the imageurls and I want to bind them in the code behind. How would I go about do that? I want the datalist to have a max column size of 5 and add rows of thumbnails until completed.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" 
          RepeatColumns="5" 
          RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
          RepeatLayout="Flow">

   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Image ID="imgStore" runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

CODEBEHIND:

```
protected void BindImages(string[] imageurls)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < imageurls.Length; i++)
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will do it for you

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" 
      RepeatColumns="5" 
      RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
      RepeatLayout="Flow">

<ItemTemplate>
   <img src="<%# (string)Container.DataItem %>" />
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

Code behind

```
protected void BindImages(string[] imageurls)
{
    dlImages.DataSource = imageurls; 
    dlImages.DataBind();
}
```

You might also be able to do

```
<asp:Image runat="server" id="imgStore" 
     ImageUrl="<%# (string)Container.DataItem %>" />
```

But sometimes server controls don't like render blocks in them.

Comment: This works great if I use actual imageurls, but if I use ones that I created for example: ~/UserPages/Photo/GetThumbnail.aspx?id=7...It doesn't work.